# GRPC request gives different response with multiple instances

Tags: python, tensorflow, subprocess, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to do model prediction through tensorflow serving through grpc connection and my main code runs with multiple instances. I send Predict request with the following code

```py
req = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
req.model_spec.name = model_name
req.model_spec.signature_name = "serving_default"
req.inputs[input_layer].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(input_data))
response = stub.Predict(req, timeout)
```

Where stub is defined once and reused per instance in the following way:

```py
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    grpc_connection_path, options=options,
)
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
```

So I was trying to make grpc unavailable by removing the unix socket file and after this for one instance running prediction gives the following error:

> Error: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
> details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: No such file or directory"
> debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Failed to pick subchannel {created_time:"2022-08-25T14:04:54.24900453+00:00", children:[UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: No such file or directory {created_time:"2022-08-25T14:04:54.24900212+00:00", grpc_status:14}]}"

However, for the other instance of my prediction code it gives a normal result.  I am trying to test and handle the case where my connection is not available but I am getting mixed results on different instances.

Can you explain why can this happening?

**UPDATE**

When I run for example 20 instances I have the problem the way I described above but when I run 3 instances I do not. However in the case of 20 instances I have the problem only when I delete the unix socket file(as I described above). When the file is there everything works perfectly.

Comment: probably because its a prediction. I guess you would not get the same result if you ask the same instance twice.

Comment: no it gives the same result when asking the same instance. So the problem is not in prediction